# CameraX PreviewView to Bitmap instead of a File

Tags: android, kotlin

I know there are other questions that was answered to many times and I tried to find the answer, but I couldn't understand of it most. I want to make the camera to take a photo, but instead of making a physical image file, I want it directly to make it into a bitmap and display it in an ImageView from a different activity, however I constantly getting the `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference`, that's because of the `viewFinder.bitmap` is a null and decided to make a seperate function `getBitmap(): Bitmap?`. I don't know what it wants me to do honestly or any lead from this, all I want to do is to make the photo straight to ImageView as a bitmap. Thank you in advance.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.camerax5, PID: 5472
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.camerax5/com.example.camerax5.VirtualPreview}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3284)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1972)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7179)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:164)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:677)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:842)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:809)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:633)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:259)
        at com.example.camerax5.MainActivity.getBitmap(MainActivity.kt:118)
        at com.example.camerax5.VirtualPreview.onCreate(VirtualPreview.kt:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7335)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
```

So the problem was occured on this line:

```
viewFinder = findViewById(R.id.previewView)
```

Here is the full code of what I was trying to do:

MainActivity.kt and underneath the MainActivity code is the other class with another activity to show the bitmap in the ImageView, I added this way is because I don't want to separate them and making them confusing:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewFinder = findViewById(R.id.previewView)

        //Permissions
        if (allPermissions()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

        //Capture button
        val captureBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.captureButton)
        captureBtn.setOnClickListener {
            takePhoto()
        }

        outputDirectory = outputDirectoryFolder()

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

private fun takePhoto() {
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Processing ..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        //Directly to open the new Activity
        val intent = Intent(this, VirtualPreview::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    fun getBitmap(): Bitmap? {
        //Preview to Bitmap
        viewFinder = findViewById(R.id.previewView)
        val source = viewFinder.bitmap
        val newWidth = 200
        val newHeight = 200

        val bitmapWidth = source?.width
        val bitmapHeight = source?.height

        //Matrix
        val matrix = Matrix()
        val scaleWidth = newWidth.toFloat() / bitmapWidth!!
        val scaleHeight = newHeight.toFloat() / bitmapHeight!!
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, matrix, true)
    }
}

class VirtualPreview : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var acceptButton: Button
    private lateinit var denyButton: Button
    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_virtual_preview)

        val bitmapPreview = MainActivity().getBitmap()

        val drawableBitmap = BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmapPreview)
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imagePreview)
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawableBitmap)

        acceptButton = findViewById(R.id.acceptButton)
        acceptButton.setOnClickListener {

        }

        denyButton = findViewById(R.id.denyButton)
        denyButton.setOnClickListener {
            //delete the matrix and returns to the main activity
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `val bitmapPreview = MainActivity().getBitmap()` – You cannot create an instance of `MainActivity` like that. The system must handle `Activity` instantiation.

Comment: Since passing large bitmaps between activities does not work well (too large), either use one activity and two fragments, or *carefully* use some sort of singleton that both activities can reach.

Answer (score 0):

`val bitmapPreview = MainActivity().getBitmap()` - This way you are creating a new instance of `MainActivity` and the new instance do not have any thing in preview view, also this method is not recommended. Better store bitmap inside MainActivity and then pass that bitmap to `VirtualPreview` activity in constructor (in bundle it won't work). It won't be a problem for your case, as you're scaling the bitmap to 200x200. and for large bitmap, store in file, and use that file. And for your case, you can create another imageview in mainactivity and show the bitmap in that imageview instead of creating another activity.

Comment: That's good to know, however my goal was to make an actual bitmap virtually and not making it a file yet, let's just say I want to get a specific frame from the Preview and then make a bitmap in full size, for the scaling I'll fix that

Comment: @GeorgiTasev you can store small bitmap in memory but for large bitmap is not a good idea. However, you can store bitmap in memory and pass that bitmap to the other activity in constructor, but in bundle it won't work.

Comment: I see, so the preview view bitmap is a large one, right.

Comment: @GeorgiTasev no, you're not getting bitmap from this call `val bitmapPreview = MainActivity().getBitmap()` .